# Manage derived classes via a base class when using GetComponent in Unity?

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine, casting

Whenever I try to set up an inheritance hierarchy, I find myself trapped in this scenario over and over.

In the current form, I have a base class that represent all UI elements in my game. I called this class, UI_Toggleable. This class has an enum property that each derived class can set. Here is brief look as to how the code looks like:

```
public class UI_Toggleable 
{

    // The Menu Type enum that all derived classes must define.
    protected UIMenus menuType;

    // Gives any child of this class a toggle function
    // to enable/disable UI when needed.
    public void ToggleUI()
    {
        // Toggle Code
    }

    // Public property Getter - Read Only Access.
    // Only derived classes can define the value of the menu type.
    public virtual UIMenus MenuType
    {
        get { return menuType; }
    }
}
```

Now, say a class called InventoryUI derives from Toggleable, we have the following.

```
 public class  InventoryUI : UI_Toggleable
{

    private void Awake()
    {
        _instance = this;
        menuType = UIMenus.Inventory;
    }

    public override UIMenus MenuType
    {
        get { return menuType; }
    }
}
```

Now, if I try to implement a manager for these objects, I will want to get the menu type of each derived class. However, I do not want to ASSUME the type of the UI_Toggleable class. Instead, what I am trying to do is to get any of the derived classes as a UI_Toggleable, and then proceed to call the MenuType method to get its type regardless.

```
UI_Toggleable toggleable = GetComponent<UI_Toggleable>();
toggleable.MenuType;
```

The problem with the above is, it would return me the MenuType of the base class instead of the derived class I retrieved as a base class. And that is somewhat expected, but I want to get the MenuType of the derived class WITHOUT doing the following:

```
if(GetComponent<UI_Toggleable>() is  InventoryUI )
 InventoryUI toggleable = GetComponent< InventoryUI >();
toggleable.MenuType;
```

The above works, but it defeats the purpose of me setting up a base class that shares similar properties with children. Doing all these casts and checks just makes the code appear difficult to read and decouple.

Other things I tried include the following:

- Create an interface IMenuType that defines a function GetMenuType. Each derived class implements the method, and in my manager, I would do the check `if(toggleable is IMenuType)`. And if true, then attempt to call ((IMenuType)toggleable).GetMenuType.
- Let the MenuType property getter be an abstract function that each derived class must implement. But similar to the above cases, I still have to make cast checks before attempting to call the method.
- Although not my priority, the MenuType method was not meant to be virtual.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to solve a problem without exactly knowing how to, what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Seems to me your design is flawed - if you need to know which type of derived type it is when you call it you will have to do `x is MyClass`...and then proceed to do something derived-class-specific on the object. If you're doing something generic then you don't need to know - just use the derived class calls.

Comment: Wait a minute, does `UI_Toggleable` inherit from `MonoBehaviour`? Things are not really going to work if it doesn't.

Comment: Why not just do `GetComponent<InventoryUI>()` right away? if it does not have a InventoryUI component the call will return null.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - you can't really get to it in C#... Plus OP claims that they get correct type anyway - `GetComponent<UI_Toggleable>() is  InventoryUI` ...

Comment: @Liam Ah, C#, not C++! You're right, I'm sorry! I stopped reading after "The problem with the above is, it would return me the MenuType of the base class instead of the derived class I retrieved as a base class."

Comment: Seems like you are reinventing the wheel, I would use types from UnityEngine.UI instead, they are completely customisable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting `menuType` of the base class correctly. Rather than setting it in the `Awake` method of derived classes, set it in the constructor, like this:

```
public class UI_Toggleable {
    public UIMenus MenuType {get;}
    // Subclasses must pass the correct menuType here
    protected UI_Toggleable(UIMenus menuType) {
        MenuType = menuType;
    }
}
public class  InventoryUI : UI_Toggleable {
    // Pass the proper menu type for storing inside the base class
    public InventoryUI() : base(UIMenus.Inventory) {
    }
}
```

Note how `MenuType` is now a read-only property of the base class, rather than a virtual property with overriding.

> I cannot really use the constructor. Is it acceptable if I set it in the `Awake` method instead?

It appears from your code sample that `Awake` is not being called in time for the base class to supply the correct value. In this case you go with an `abstract` getter-only property, like this:

```
public class UI_Toggleable {
    public abstract UIMenus MenuType {get;}
}
public class  InventoryUI : UI_Toggleable {
    public override UIMenus MenuType {
        get => UIMenus.Inventory
    }
}
```

**Note:** Legacy syntax for `get => UIMenus.Inventory` is `get { return UIMenus.Inventory; }`

Comment: If I use the above, and then try and access my object as a UI_Toggleable (eventhough it's actually one of its children), will getting the MenuType property retrieve the one modified by the child? If that is the case, then that is exactly what I need! I failed to mention in the question that it is a Monobehaviour script, so I cannot really use the constructor. Is it acceptable if I set it in the Awake method instead?

Comment: @AAS.N You get the value supplied by the child class to the constructor of the base class. If you must use `Awake`, things get trickier; please see the edit.

Comment: I actually tried the first idea by setting the base.menuType variable in the Awake method of the child class. To my surprise, it seems to work! I can simply get the MenuType directly from the base class now without having to cast and check individual child classes. Also, I do not think your edit will work in my scenario, as the intention is to call the MenuType property from the base class. Seeing that it's abstract, it should throw a compile error at me -- that is at least what happened on one of my iterations of this code. Can you confirm?

Comment: @AAS.N Calling an abstract method will not throw an exception, or create a compile-time problem. The compiler knows that by the time the call is made, the property has been safely overridden, so it permits the call even from the base class. You wouldn't be able to instantiate your base class directly, though, but you shouldn't be doing it either way.